# Java mail message body is html but type is text/plain - read html

Tags: html, jakarta-mail, message

The body of the message I receive is html structured but the type of the message says text/plain. In javax.mail getContent() returns plain text instead of html structured text. Even getBodyPart() returns just text.

Is there a way of actually extracting the html formatted message body from an email message marked as text/plain?

```
Object content = inMessage.getContent();
MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) content;
BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
String cnt = (String) bodyPart.getContent());
```

cnt is a plain text instead of being html formatted. I know it is html because Outlook reads it as html and ViewSource in Outlook is html email.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The multipart message might be a multipart/alternative that includes both the plain text and html parts.  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).