# Determine message body type if mime type is unknown

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

We fetch mails (pop3) using java mail API and store them in database. We store the html body and the text body in different columns, respectively. Most of the mails both have text and html parts and we store both of them. To determine whether the body is html or text we use the following method

```
public void dumpPart(part p..) {

if (p.isMimeType("text/html")) {
//store as html body
} else if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
// store as text body
} else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative)) {
// get parts in a loop and call dumpPart recursively again
} else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
// get parts in a loop and call dumpPart recursively again
} else if (p.isMimeType("rfc..)) {
// 
} else {
//handle unknown mime type
```

When we fall in the case of unknown mime type, some mails have a type of String object when called getContent(), and the string contains an html body. But we have to distinguish whether it is a text message or html message. Any suggestion/idea better then looking for html tags to determine the string corresponds to an html or not?

Another question, in our current implementation, we did not check for the case **text/plain**, but if the if fails for **text/***, does it mean it will also return false for **text/plain**? (We do not have the problematic mail in the mailserver anymore I can not debug, we need a solution to sort out same problematic cases in the future)

I think our case is the line 299-302 of the msgshow.java at

https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java

here we got the string but do not know if html or plain text?

A similar question is at

[Java mail message body is html but type is text/plain - read html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772105/java-mail-message-body-is-html-but-type-is-text-plain-read-html?rq=1)

but in our case the message fails also the multipart case

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody

Comment: It would be really helpful to see a sample message that causes the problem to figure out what you  might be doing wrong.  Checking for "text/*" should match "text/plain".

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary=--boundary_21776656_..
Message-ID: <0.0..>

----boundary_21776656_--..
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+PGh..
----boundary_21776656_--..
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PHAgZGlyPSJsdH..  

we have somepart, it says conten-type text/plain but if we decode we see HTML content with <html><head><meta.. headers. and the other part says it has content-type text/html and if we decode we get text with only <p> tags (no <html><meta> etc)

Comment: we can not fetch the message from the ms again but he have stored the main headers when we fetched. we see that sender sets text/plain for the html (includes <html><meta etc) content and text/html for text based content (contains pure string with some <p>... Is there any workaround to determine it correctly even if sender sets wrong type?

Comment: The only workaround would be some heuristic in your application.  Obviously the best approach is to get the sender to fix their application.  Do you know what application was used to send the message?